# Установить фокус в поле при появлении диалога

Tags: gwt, java

Для этого есть метод setFocus. Но непонятно, как его использовать. Как сделать так, чтобы при каждом появлении диалога, сразу фокус вставал в текстовое поля внутри этого диалога?

Comment: Мне кажется что должен быть тупо параметр у компонента формы.
Аля DefaultFocus как в делфи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить диалогу слушатель события attach (будет реагировать как на attach, так и на detach), в обработке attach добавлять в очередь событий нашу команду (установка фокуса)

```
addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {
  public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent e) {
    if (e.isAttached()) {
      Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
        public void execute() {
          textBox.setFocus(true);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**jTextField.setFocus(true);**

jTextField - имя вашего поля класса JTextField (либо любой другой класс текстовых полей)

Эту строчку пишите в конструктор после инициализации вашего текстового поля. Тогда поле будет получать фокус сразу при создании формы.

Comment: Это не имеет никакого отношения к GWT.

Comment: пардон, на метки не посмотрел, а в вопросе про отношение к gwt нет ничего (: